# How can I use normals from OBJ file for diffuse lighting?

Tags: opengl, lighting

I'm trying implement diffuse lighting. My vertex and fragment shader looks like this:

```
#version 150

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 color;
attribute vec3 normal;

out vec3 inColor;
out vec3 inNormal;
out vec3 inPosition;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main(void) {

        gl_Position = transform * vec4(position,  1.0);
        inColor = color;
        inNormal = normal;
        inPosition = position;
    }

------------------------------------
#version 150

out vec4 outColor;
in vec3 inColor;
in vec3 inNormal;
in vec3 inPosition;

uniform vec3 lightPosition;

void main(void) {    
    vec3 lightVector = normalize(lightPosition - inPosition);
    float brightness =  clamp(dot(lightVector, inNormal), 0, 1);
    outColor = vec4(brightness, brightness, brightness, 1.0f);
}
```

The question is: What am I suppose to do with the normals after I load them from OBJ file?

Comment: What do you mean what are you supposed to do? You wrote the shader but didn't send them to the graphics card?

Comment: I sent them to graphics card but the result is: http://prnt.sc/db8q57. The light is above the sphere. I'm trying figure out what causes the problem. I'm not sure if I should do something with the normals before I send them to graphics card or just send them there after I read them from OBJ file.

Comment: Are your normals normalised? Try normalizing inNormal before you dot it with lightVector. Hang on, have you done any transforms on the object? If you've rotated the object you need to multiply the normals by the rotation matrix. Also, if the object is translated, then the position of the vertex you need to send to the fragment shader is inPosition = modelMatrix * position;

Comment: Apart from normalization, the picture looks as if some of the normals have the wrong orientation (i.e. pointing inwards).

Comment: I've tried the normalization and the result looks like this: http://prnt.sc/db8vuk

Comment: Have you done any transforms to the object before sending it to the shaders? rotations? translations? If not then you should check the normals. You said they were from an obj file, maybe they're wrong?  I think Nico is right, some of the triangle's normals look inverted.

Comment: Those are might wrong normals yes, could you show how do you get those normals? Or how did you export your obj if you exported it.

Comment: I haven't done any transformation and this is my OBJ loader: https://github.com/kohuthonza/ElasticObjects/blob/master/ElasticObjects/OBJ_Loader.cpp

Comment: if some of your normals are wrongly oriented (common for obj files) then just use `abs(dot(...))` instead of `dot(...)` that will shine on both sides of polygon ...

Comment: The .obj format has a flipped y-axis when compared to OpenGL's coordinate system. Have you adjusted for this?